# can we pass extra parameter to a beego router

Tags: sql, go, controller, beego

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *MainController) Post() {
    var datapoint User
    req := this.Ctx.Input.RequestBody
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(req), &datapoint)
    this.Ctx.WriteString("hello world")
    //  result := this.Input()
    fmt.Println("input value is", datapoint.UserId)

}
```

this is normal beego router which executes on url occurrence. I want something like

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *MainController,db *sql.DB) Post() {

    fmt.Println("input value is", datapoint.UserId)

}
```

in order to use database connection pointer. is this possible to achieve this using go...if not please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in golang

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller }

func (this *MainController,db *sql.DB) Post() {

    fmt.Println("input value is", datapoint.UserId)

}
```

the declaration in the form

```
function (c *MainController)Post()
```

means that Post is a method for the `MainController` struct you can pass variable into it.

My suggestion is you declare the db pointer as a global variable in your package like below then you will be able to use it inside the `Post` function

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

var db *sql.DB

func (this *MainController) Post() {
    //you can now use the variable db inside here
    fmt.Println("input value is", datapoint.UserId)

}
```

but considering this is Beego which uses the MVC pattern you can do all this from within the model. I suggest you take a look at their awesome [documentation here](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/overview.md)

Comment: exactly i was trying the same thing meanwhile you have posted what i was trying to do.....it is working for me